# Single sign on Java and NodeJs (Share single session object between Java and Nodejs)

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-mvc, express

I developed two application. One application developed by using Java(Spring MVC and Spring Security) and another application developed by using NodeJs.
I would like to integrate NodeJs application in Java application(Spring framwork application) . I would like to access(Call) the NodeJs application after login into Java application.
I checked in forum but I am not get in clear view.

E.g) My situation is, I have one hyperlink in Java (Hyperlink will show after login) and call NodeJs application if user click on that hyperlink.

Can you please give the some examples and ideas for integrating NodeJs and Java applicaton and also for sharing session between Java and NodeJs application?

Comment: use loader balancer for manage http request, and handle them by java or nodejs. Or a litle simple solution use different ports. For sharing session please see article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Okay thanks.I can use HTTP access control in hyperlink click event to access the NodeJs application URL and send Java session object(Assume I can call NodeJs application url from JSP page). Normally in NodeJs, We are assigning and retrieving session value like req.session.username. But how can I retrieve value  from Java session object in NodeJs? Can you please guide me to achieve this?

Comment: You can use cookies and save sessionid. I done this uproach in one of my project. 1) var cookies = require('express/node_modules/cookie').parse(req.headers.cookie) 2) parsed = require('express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils').parseSignedCookies(cookies, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); 3) get data from session  session_setting.store.get(parsed['connect.sid'], function(err, session){})

Comment: Based on your reply,I added code and tested the application. But I am not able to get infomation from Java session Object.
I am added needed code here, can you Please check this

Comment: var express = require('express'), cookies = require('cookie'), parsed = require('utils'), connect = require("connect");
var sessionKey = 'connect.sid';
var sessionStore = new connect.middleware.session.MemoryStore();
var app = express();
var secreatKey = '123456789456';
app.use(express.cookieParser(secreatKey));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.session({ store: sessionStore, key: sessionKey }));

Comment: //Here I am getting session value from request
var cookies1 = cookies.parse(req.headers.cookie); 
var parsed1 = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(cookies1, secreatKey);
console.log("connect.sid : " + JSON.stringify(parsed1, null, "    ")); 
sessionStore.get(parsed1[sessionKey], function(err, session){  
  console.log("sessiontest: " + JSON.stringify(session)); 
});

Comment: Sample Output:
I am getting output like that below only, but I am not getting value from Java session object.
In java I used HttpSession object for storing the value.
connect.sid : {
    "connect.sid": "BpNoHmwPCjcVoki2XzYMfROW"
}

Comment: {
    "cookie": {
        "originalMaxAge": null,
        "expires": null,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "path": "/"
    },
    "passport": {
        "user": 2
    },
    "flash": {},
    "username": Mano // This vaue from session but this is com from nodejs session , not from java session
}

Comment: How can I get information from Java session object?
Can you please correct me if I did any mistake in code?

Comment: you need use one session store for java and nodejs. Dont use MemoryStore. Setup you java and node use one database or radis for storing sessions.

Comment: I am doing first task in NodeJs. let me check, how to create radis store for storing sessions values.

Comment: use express instead pure nodejs, it will be simple for you in begining. Radis implemintation for session store https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

Comment: Okay.suppose if I use radis store in nodejs express 3.2.6, I want to do anything on java(Spring application) side. Is Radis store medium to connect Java application and NodeJs for sharing session data? . One more question, Is we need to connect radis store to daatabase(I am using mysql)?

Comment: I have downloaded Radis server pachage for windows7. So, Shall I need to start Radis server seperatly if I use Radis store?

Comment: Sorry for more question . I refereed this site, so that I am asking. http://spring.io/blog/2011/05/03/using-mongodb-redis-node-js-and-spring-mvc-in-a-single-cloud-foundry-application/

Comment: Can you please add me some more extra information for getting java (Spring application)session object from NodeJs application.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your web apps behind proxy server to avoid the CORS problem and for sharing the session you would use [Redis](http://redis.io/) DB.
After it you will need just to check session expiration on your NodeJs app.